# iframe is in Spanish, but generates in English

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, iframe

I am using an iframe such as:

```
<iframe class="scholarship-form" title="Scholarship Submission in Spanish" src="https://massmutualfuturesmart.creativezing.com/?language=es
" width="100%" height="1050"></iframe>
```

I have even tried:

```
<iframe class="scholarship-form" title="Scholarship Submission in Spanish" src="https://massmutualfuturesmart.creativezing.com/?language=es&display=undefined
" width="100%" height="1050"></iframe>
```

...with no luck the iframe still appears in English for some reason. Can someone provide a solution for this issue? Thank you!

The page in question is: https://futuresmart.massmutual.com/es/beca/

[Error Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyCHG.png)

Comment: The link https://massmutualfuturesmart.creativezing.com/?language=es doesn't show up in spanish. It appears in English. That means the parameter language isn't working.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with being in an iFrame. That source is not in Spanish. Where is the Spanish version of the form held?